# How to compile C without a main function using CL?

Tags: windows, cl

I'm trying to create a PE binary (or lib) using CL so I can explore the produced assembly language? The code I have is simple:

**test.c**

```
void f() { return; };
```

And that's it. I compile like so:

```
cl /Od test.c
```

And I get the error `LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined`. I kinda knew this would happen because I know the compiler expects an entry point.

But how can I compile the code without any entry points to inspect the assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to assemble the code only and to not invoke the linker as per the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/ml-and-ml64-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019):

```
cl /Od /c test.c
```